# Replace n-th occurrence of a word

Tags: vim

I am using vim to edit a huge file-I want to replace the 100th occurence of 'Luke' with 'The chosen one'. I searched the Internet for a possible solution and I guess I should do somethink like /Luke and then hitting the 'n' key 99 times, but I find this a bit tedious. Is there any easier way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*next* supports a count

```
99n
```

should do

Otherwise, you could play with `:global` (it's a little bit overkill)

```
:let c = 0
:g/Luke/let c+=1|if c==100|s//This one!/|endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can script something, using `feedkeys()` function and using `:s` commadn with the "c" flag. [On the mailinglist, this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/ZbqpqIwSeWs/bzRB3KODVwUJ) was once suggested.